# convert VLP16 sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 to sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Tags: ros, vlp16, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to test a library that require a sensor *_msgs/LaserScan* topic.
I found this question http://answers.ros.org/question/9450/how-to-setup-pointcloud_to_laserscan/ but I am pretty new to ROS and I have a lot of difficulties in adapting this solution to my case.
Could you help me with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249537/convert-vlp16-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2-to-sensor_msgs/laserscan/) by [ESeNonFossiIo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28743/esenonfossiio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2016-12-07**:
What's the problem in your case? What exactly is the error when you run that launch file?

**Comment by [ESeNonFossiIo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28743/esenonfossiio/) on 2016-12-07**:
I do not know how to write a launch file for the VLP16. I got two default launch files but they are supposed to work with Kinect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is Velodyne specific software:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/pull/110
http://wiki.ros.org/but_velodyne_proc#Laserscan_Node

Edit: Added velodyne_laserscan pull request

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ESeNonFossiIo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28743/esenonfossiio/) on 2016-12-07**:
I couldn't compile it on my laptop. I got:

```
but_calibration_camera_velodyne/Calibration.h:53:24: error: ‘isnan’ was not declared in this scope
 return !isnan(value);
```

**Comment by [ESeNonFossiIo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28743/esenonfossiio/) on 2016-12-09**:
Using your branch it seems working.
I see **/scan** and the output is ok.